# How should std::atomic_...<std::shared_ptr> be used in the copy and move operations of a thread safe class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

I have the following class that is supposed to be thread safe and has a `std::shared_ptr` member that refers to some shared resource.

```
class ResourceHandle
{
    using Resource = /* unspecified */;
    std::shared_ptr<Resource> m_resource;
};
```

Multiple threads may acquire a copy of a resource handle from some central location and the central resource handle may be updated at any time. So reads and writes to the same ResourceHandle may take place concurrently.

```
// Centrally:
ResourceHandle rh;

// Thread 1: reads the central handle into a local copy for further processing
auto localRh = rh;

// Thread 2: creates a new resource and updates the central handle
rh = ResourceHandle{/* ... */};
```

Because these threads perform non-const operations on the same `std::shared_ptr`, according to [CppReference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), I should use the `std::atomic_...<std::shared_ptr>` specializations to manipulate the shared pointer.

> If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without
>   synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member
>   function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur; the shared_ptr
>   overloads of atomic functions can be used to prevent the data race.

So I want to implement the copy and move operations of the `ResourceHandle` class using these atomic operations such that manipulating a single resource handle from multiple threads avoids all data races.

The notes section of the [CppReference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) on `std::atomic_...<std::shared_ptr>` specializations states the following:

> To avoid data races, once a shared pointer is passed to any of these
>   functions, it cannot be accessed non-atomically. In particular, you
>   cannot dereference such a shared_ptr without first atomically loading
>   it into another shared_ptr object, and then dereferencing through the
>   second object.

So I probably want to use some combination of `std::atomic_load` and `std::atomic_store`, but I am unsure where and when they should be applied.

**How should the copy and move operations of my `ResourceHandle` class be implemented to not introduce any data races?**

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand what you are asking here. Why should a widget be copyable at all? Where is the atomic that you don't use? Which class is "basically [..] the C++17 equivalent" of an atomic shared pointer?

Comment: `shared_ptr` already has atomic copy and move operations.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Okay, Widget might indeed be a bad name, I'll change it. But the class is a kind of handle that provided access to a shared resource. Multiple threads may want a handle to the same resource and may acquire a copy from some central location. However, this handle may also be written to at any time. So, I want the copy/move operations to be thread safe. Does that make a bit more sense? If not, how could I make it more clear what I am asking?

Comment: Are you intending to move / swap a new `Resource` into the object owned by the `m_resource`, or to modify `m_resource` to own a different `Resource`?

Comment: @Caleth My intention is to modify `m_resource` to own a a different `Resource`.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have updated the question with some snippet of how it is used and explained my thought process some more of how I arrived at the `std::atomic_...` specializations. If something is still unclear, please indicate how I can improve the question.

Comment: Your question is much clearer now! Also, and that was unclear before, you don't seem to mix up pointer and pointee, which is a typical beginners' mistake. Just for the record though, you will have to synchronize access to the resource as well, not just to the pointer.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt While it has fallen out of fashion, `class Widget` was the `struct Foo` of the 1990s and early 2000s. Scott Meyers uses the term extensively in his Items, iirc.

Answer (score 2):

`std::shared_ptr` synchronises it's access to the reference count, so you don't have to worry about operations on one `std::shared_ptr` affecting another. If those are followed by at least one modification to the pointee, you have a data race *there*. Code that shares ownership of a previous `Resource` will be unaffected by `m_resource` being reset to point to a new `Resource`.

You have to synchronise access to a *single* `std::shared_ptr`, if that is accessible in multiple threads. The warning provided (and the reason it is deprecated in C++20) states that if *anywhere* is atomically accessing a value, *everywhere* that accesses that value should be atomic.

You could achieve that by hiding the global `std::shared_ptr` behind a local copies. `ResourceHandle` as a separate class makes that more difficult.

```
using ResourceHandle = std::shared_ptr<Resource>;
static ResourceHandle global;

ResourceHandle getResource()
{
    return std::atomic_load(&global);
}

void setResource(ResourceHandle handle)
{
    std::atomic_store(&global, handle);
}
```

Comment: And will there be no data race if one thread makes a copy of a particular `ResourceHandle` while another thread assigns something to that same `ResourceHandle`? So one thread is reading `m_resource` while another is assigning to that same `m_resource`.

Comment: Are you sure `std::shared` has atomic operations? I know that `boost::shared_ptr` used atomic operations to update the reference counter in its implementation, but that doesn't make the shared pointer object itself atomic!

Comment: Yep, that's it now and I just stopped typing an own answer to that question. There's only one thing that I'd like to emphasize though: Not the class (ResourceHandle) is made threadsafe! Only certain operations on one specific instance of that class are made threadsafe because only that instance is also used by different threads. This is often a better approach than trying to make classes some kind of synchronized.

Comment: I appreciate the answer and the proposed approach, thanks! However, I will not accept it as the answer because I am really looking for the correct use of `std::atomic_load` and `std::atomic_store` in the copy/move constructor and copy/move assignment of the `ResourceHandle` class.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis The problem with that is you need atomicness not as a property of the *type* `ResourceHandle`, but of the *particular instance* of that type. In C++20 you might be able to specialise `std::atomic<ResourceHandle>` to use `std::atomic<std::shared_ptr<Resource>>`, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: And you still have to synchronise access to the `Resource`, if anything can modify it.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis, that is the wrong approach! You wouldn't just have to implement assignment and copying, but also read-only access to the shared_ptr instance within your `ResourceHandle` class to accomodate for the use limits that you found out yourself. Also, if I copy the shared instance `rh`, I'd be willing to pay the price, but if I did something like `auto anotherLocalRh = localRh;`, why should I pay any performance penalty for the synchronization overhead there?

Comment: Hmmm... valid comments from both of you, and food for thought. Perhaps it's time for me to take a step back and look at the bigger picture instead of focusing on this one thing!

Comment: Relevant to the discussion, C++20 partially specializes `std::atomic` for `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic2